# ftps server error GnuTLS error -89: Public key signature verification has failed

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, tls1.2, ftps

I Created FTPS server with `ftpserver-core 1.0.6 library` and use keystore with JKS format. I implemented by 2 ways below but the second way I got the issue:

> GnuTLS error -89: Public key signature verification has failed.

1. Using keystore JKS which generated from keytool java: The ftps server is working.
2. Create Keystore with exist Certificate from customer. At that way, I get certificates chain by X509Certificate format and I create keystore with jks format. The server started normally but I could not connect to the server via FTP client (FileZilla)

I think that there is something wrong with my certificates chain format. How can i check the format of Certificate chain of keystore which generate by keytool.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my mistake. The private key which i used to generate file keystore was different from the privateKey of certificate.